# how to convert string to listviewitem?

Tags: c#

I try to convert `string` to `ListViewItem`:

```
ListViewItem str = (ListViewItem)Convert.ChangeType(az, typeof(ListViewItem));
```

but it doesn't work. What is wrong in this code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not sure I get why you are trying to change the type of a string to ListViewItem. I'm pretty sure that what you actually want to do is create a ListViewItem out of a string using regular construction:

```
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(az);
```